# Can I configure ModelMapper to use a converter for all properties with the source type?

Tags: java, modelmapper

I'm trying to configure ModelMapper to use a certain converter for all properties that implement a certain interface, across any entity class. I can get everything working by defining a TypeMap for each entity, and defining mappings for each relevant property, but I'm hoping there's a simpler way that doesn't need to be updated anytime a property is added.

So far I have something like this:

```
public interface Labelled { String getLabel; // returns a message code }
public class Vegetable implements labelled { ... }
public class Protein implements labelled { ... }
public class Starch implements labelled { ... }
public class Dinner { Vegetable veg; Starch starch; Protein protein; String name; // getters and setters }
public class DinnerDto { String veg; String starch; String protein; String name; // get/set }

public class LabelledToStringConverter extends AbstractConverter<Labelled, String> {
      private final MessageSource messageSource;

    public LabelledToStringConverter(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @Override
    protected String convert(Labelled labelled) {
        final Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        final String messageCode = labelled.getLabel();
        return messageSource.getMessage(messageCode, null, messageCode, locale);
    }
}

@Configuration
public class Configuration {
    @Bean
    public ModelMapper modelMapper(final MessageSource messageSource) {
        final ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
        final Converter<Labelled, String> converter = new LabelledToStringConverter(messageSource);
        mapper.createTypeMap(Dinner.class, DinnerDto.class)
                .addMappings(map -> {
                    map.using(converter).map(Dinner::getVegetable, DinnerDto::setVegetable);
                    map.using(converter).map(Dinner::getProtein, DinnerDto::setProtein);
                    map.using(converter).map(Dinner::getStarch, DinnerDto::setStarch);
                });
        return mapper;
    }
```

...but I'd prefer to avoid mapping each individual field, and if possible each type. `TypeMap.setPropertyConverter` doesn't work when there are fields of other types. `ModelMap.addConverter` doesn't appear to do anything (I've tried both implementing `Converter` and extending `AbstractConverter`).

Is there another way to configure ModelMapper with my converter and have it apply that to all relevant fields without explicitly defining a mapping for each one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than calling `ModelMapper.addConverter`, which actually creates or adds to a `TypeMap` under the hood, a converter can be added to ModelMapper's implicit mapping by implementing `ConditionalConverter` and adding our converter directly to the underlying configuration. The converter class:

```
// Our converter will implement ConditionalConverter instead
public class LabelledToStringConverter implements ConditionalConverter<Labelled, String> {
      private final MessageSource messageSource;

    public LabelledToStringConverter(MessageSource messageSource) {
        this.messageSource = messageSource;
    }

    @Override
    public MatchResult match(Class<?> sourceType, Class<?> destinationType) {
        return Labelled.class.isAssignableFrom(sourceType) && String.class.isAssignableFrom(destinationType)
                ? MatchResult.FULL : MatchResult.NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public String convert(MappingContext<Labelled, String> context) {
        if (context.getSource() == null) {
            return null;
        }
        final Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
        final String messageCode = context.getSource().getLabel();
        return messageSource.getMessage(messageCode, null, messageCode, locale);
    }
}
```

The `ModelMapper` setup:

```
final ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.getConfiguration().getConverters().add(new LabelledToStringConverter(messageSource));
// Do any other explicit type mapping necessary, e.g. where names don't match
```

This will use the converter implementation anytime the conditions are matched, here anytime the model mapper is converting a property from `Labelled` to `String`.